# How to get rid of Skype?

Tags: skype, 19.04, activities-overview

I'm on Ubuntu **19.04**:

[image]

**Tried:**

[image]

But it still appears under **Activities**:

[image]

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: I think You have `skypeforlinux.desktop` (or similar name) file somewhere in Your filesystem, try searching for it and delete it.

Comment: `sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux.desktop` solved the problem. Thanks. It is a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. There should be a `Skype.desktop` file. Delete it, and it should be gone the next time you log in.

Failing that, there may be another .desktop file at `/usr/share/applications/`.

Comment: Thank you! In fact `~/.local/share/applications/` doesn't contain such an entry.  `sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux.desktop` solved the problem

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't entirely sure of the exact Skype name for the file. Looks like it was a reasonable approximation to find it though.